# ubuntu VM gets stuck and can't reach login page when launching on virtualbox (Windows host OS)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, display-settings

**issue:**

When I launch my Ubuntu 20.04 VM with virtual box 6.1, everything goes as normal up until the retrieving the log in page. 
At this point I am instead presented with a blank and unresponsive (I can't type in it) terminal and nothing seems to happen.

I have ubuntu 20.04 LTS
My host operating system is windows 10

**Background:**

My machine worked before- but after a while of disuse- rather than logging me out- it would take me to this frozen terminal instead. 
I tried fiddling around with display setting, but the situation, but this may have made things worse as I cannot reach the login page at all now. I have attached images on the blank terminal and some of my settings to help identify the issue, any help would be massively appreciated!

[frozen terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqF9v.png)

[display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL3Mp.png)

[storage settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqhcf.png)

Comment: Just a question of clarification. Ubuntu likes to show a login screen, then a screen covering the login, then black. Pressing Escape when this screen is active brings back login for me. Is this what you see, or is the machine frozen.

Comment: I am afraid pressing escape doesn't work. In this case the login screen never showed up in the first place, it goes straight to this blank terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am not sure how to repair Linux machines like we do Windows machines. Do you have a backup of the VM that you can restore?

Comment: @John, I haven't backed it up, it wouldn't be a disaster if I lose things but it would be a bit of a pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching to a different tty by pressing `ctrl+alt+F2`, `F3` or some other function key.

It may be that Xorg broke and you can't login anymore.

(too low reputation to comment so I'm answering)

Comment: awsome, this enabled the terminal to become responsive - from here I made some updates in the command line and this seemed to fix things

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted then, thank you!